# Filter Data In a Cleaner/More Efficient Way

Tags: performance, matlab, filtering, octave

I have a set of data with a bunch of columns. Something like the following (in reality my data has about half a million rows):

```
big = [
    1 1 0.93 0.58;
    1 2 0.40 0.34;
    1 3 0.26 0.31;
    1 4 0.40 0.26;
    2 1 0.60 0.04;
    2 2 0.84 0.55;
    2 3 0.53 0.72;
    2 4 0.00 0.39;
    3 1 0.27 0.51;
    3 2 0.46 0.18;
    3 3 0.61 0.01;
    3 4 0.07 0.04;
    4 1 0.26 0.43;
    4 2 0.77 0.91;
    4 3 0.49 0.80;
    4 4 0.40 0.55;
    5 1 0.77 0.40;
    5 2 0.91 0.28;
    5 3 0.80 0.65;
    5 4 0.05 0.06;
    6 1 0.41 0.37;
    6 2 0.11 0.87;
    6 3 0.78 0.61;
    6 4 0.87 0.51
];
```

Now, let's say I want to get rid of the rows where the first column is a `3` or a `6`.

I'm doing that like so:

```
filterRows = [3 6];

for i = filterRows 
    big = big(~ismember(1:size(big,1), find(big(:,1) == i)), :);
end
```

Which works, but the loop makes me think I'm missing a more efficient trick. Is there a better way to do this?

Originally I tried:

```
big(find(big(:,1) == filterRows ),:) = [];
```

but of course that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
rows = (big(:, 1) == 3 | big(:, 1) == 6);
big(rows, :) = [];
```

In the general case, where the values of the first column are stored in `filterRows`, you can generate the logical vector `rows` with [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
rows = ismember(big(:, 1), filterRows);
```

or with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
rows = any(bsxfun(@eq, big(:, 1), filterRows(:).'), 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. Is there a way to dynamically build that condition? The columns I want to remove wont be fixed.

Comment: Sure. `rows` is a logical (_i.e_ boolean) vector with logical "1"s (_i.e_ `true`) at the positions where your condition is satisfied. Then `big(rows, :) = []` removes them from matrix `big`. You manipulate the indexing vector `rows` in any way you want. In other words, you can assign `true` at the positions where you want the corresponding line to be removed, following any logic you want.

Comment: So it sounds as though I still need a loop to build the logical `rows` vector?

Comment: Oh, now I get you. No, you don't need a loop for that. Please see my edit.

Comment: Perfect, I've had a long day of trying to skew my brain into functional programming mode. Annoyed I missed this solution. Thank you.